# Build RCP application didn't run the lifecyclemanager

Tags: e4, java-11, eclipse-2018-12

i hope i solved all my plugin and dependency issues for my RCP application.
I hope it is my last issue, so currently if have the effect that my lifecyclemanager is not runing in the build RCP application.
I have several user permissions and i defined all views in my Application.e4xmi as invisible.

What i do in my lifecyclemanager:
- open an Logindialog
- after successful login load my user data
- set all views visible for the defined user permissions

So currently my RCP started but it is a blank window.

I already insert logmessages into the lifecyclemanager and these are not shown in the log.
I found an eclipse bug regarding this exception message but i didn't find a solution for it and the eclipse bug is already set to "Resolved Fixed".

These are the exceptions in the build RCP application log:

```
!SESSION 2019-02-15 09:09:24.364 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:26.616
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.LifeCycleManager' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.LifeCycleManager cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.025
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.application.handler.AboutHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.application.handler.AboutHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.037
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.application.handler.BookingRulesHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.application.handler.BookingRulesHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.044
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.application.handler.ChangePasswordHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.application.handler.ChangePasswordHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.050
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.parts.TimePart.handler.LastYearTimesHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.parts.TimePart.handler.LastYearTimesHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.055
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.application.handler.QuitHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.application.handler.QuitHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.062
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.application.handler.RefreshHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.application.handler.RefreshHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.068
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.parts.TimePart.handler.SubmitHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.parts.TimePart.handler.SubmitHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.075
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.parts.TimePart.handler.UnlockTimeHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.parts.TimePart.handler.UnlockTimeHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.081
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.application.handler.UsersGuideHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.application.handler.UsersGuideHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.088
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.parts.TimePart.handler.HideApprovedTimesHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.parts.TimePart.handler.HideApprovedTimesHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.094
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.parts.activityPart.handler.CollapseAllHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.parts.activityPart.handler.CollapseAllHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.100
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.parts.activityPart.handler.ShowClosedActivitiesHandler' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.parts.activityPart.handler.ShowClosedActivitiesHandler cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-15 09:09:27.796
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'app.application.StatusBar' from bundle '4'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.application.StatusBar cannot be found by app.rcp_1.0.0.201902150905
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ..
```

.

Comment: It can't find your classes. How are you building the RCP? If you are using PDE build look for a 'logs.zip' file in the build output directory which may contain messages. Check your plugin build.properties is including the '.' directory.

Comment: @greg-449
This is content of my build.properties in the RCP plugin:
`source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\ META-INF/, \ ., \icons/,\ css/default.css,\  Application.e4xmi`
      
I use the Export function on the rcp.product file.
In the log.zip file is for every plugin that i implemented the following message: option -bootclasspath not supported at compliance level 9 and above
I already checked the build compile level of the self implemented plugins and every compile level is set to JavaSE-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are getting 'option -bootclasspath not supported at compliance level 9 and above' in the logs.zip for your plugins. This is Eclipse bug [525280](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525280). Eclipse PDE build (which you are using) is broken for Java version 9 and above. There does not seem to be any prospect of this being fixed since PDE is no longer being developed.

Either back up to Java 8 or switch to using Maven with Eclipse Tycho to do the builds.